# Include Ipywidgets in chart_studio.plotly.plot

Tags: python, plotly, ipywidgets

Using this code as an example (https://plotly.com/python/figurewidget-app/):

How will I publish it to my Chart Studio account along with the widgets?

I tried using `chart_studio.plotly.plot(widgets.VBox([container,container2,g]), filename='my_graph', auto_open=True)` but it returns an exception.

And if I try `chart_studio.plotly.plot(g, filename='my_graph', auto_open=True)`, it will only show the figure but not the widgets.

How will I include the widgets for it to be interactive in my Chart Studio account?